# All Read More/Read Less opens at the same time

Tags: jquery

Used and modified the code below. Works exactly the way I need it too, but when I use it multiple times on the same page it opens all of my excerpts at the same time. Does anyone know why, and what I need to do for it to stop and open only on the items that have been clicked?

HTML:

```
<article class="excerpt">
   <h2>Title</h2>
   <p>This is a sentence...</p>
   <div class="full-story">
      <p>This is the rest of the first sentence...</p>
   </div>
   <a class="excerpt-trigger" href="#">Read More</a>
</article>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.full-story').hide();

$('.excerpt-trigger').toggle(function() {
  $('.full-story').fadeIn('slow');
  $(".excerpt-trigger").removeClass("is-more");
  $(".excerpt-trigger").addClass("is-less");
  $(this).text("Less info");
}, function() {
  $('.full-story').hide('fast');
  $(".excerpt-trigger").addClass("is-more");
  $(".excerpt-trigger").removeClass("is-less");
  $(this).text("More info");
});
```

Sorry, left out the excerpt-trigger class. Updated.

Comment: `this` is the element that was clicked that holds the handler. Use it more.

Comment: Where is the excerpt-trigger in your html?

Comment: `fadeIn` and `hide` are not complementary. Do you _want_ different animations for both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A selector such as `$('.full-story')` will select ***all*** elements that has the class `full-story`. What you want is to reference the current element being clicked on by using `$(this)`, and then selecting the very next `full-story` using `.next('.full-story')`. You can selected its children by using `.children()`, and a previous element using `.prev()`.

In your case, it should go like this:

```
$('.excerpt-trigger').toggle(function() {
    var ref = $(this); // Caching is good.
    ref.prev('.full-story').fadeIn('slow');
   ref.removeClass("is-more").addClass("is-less").text("Less info");
}, function() {
    var ref = $(this);
    ref.prev('.full-story').hide('fast');
    ref.addClass("is-more").removeClass("is-less").text("More info");
});
```

Here is the documentation on [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/), [`.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) and [`.prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/).

Additionally, you might want to prevent the event from bubbling when you click your `<a>`, so that the `href="#"` instruction is not carried over. Check out [event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/);

Comment: I'm not sure with `next`. That depends on `.except-trigger` is.

Comment: Correct, in this case I think `.children()` is what's needed. Changed my answer.

Comment: `ref.next(".excerpt-trigger")` should _almost certainly_ be just `ref`. The asker's update confirms that.

Comment: Seeing the updated code, `ref.next('.full-story')` should be `ref.prev('.full-story')`

Comment: With the code you provided (Remi) it doesn't seem to be working at all now, am I missing something.

Comment: Jan Dvorak is correct, I misread the class names. I read `$(this)` as though it was `$('excerpt')` and not `$('.excerpt-trigger')`. Rewriting the answer...